# Styling progress bar - calculating width

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I have the following code:

```css
.mod-prb {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #809097;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.mod-prb > div {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  border: inherit;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mod mod-prb">
  <div class="perc"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the `<div class="perc">` can go up to `width:95%;`. How would I go about calculating pixels so that I can use JS 1%-100%. To clarify: I'm adding width with JS, so that's not an issue.

Comment: Please add more details. It is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `.mod-prb > div` is assigned with `width` in percents with JS. Now, the problem is that I have some span, and, if I, for instance, apply `width: 98%', the `.mod-prb > div` can't fit into `mod-prb`. So, what I'm asking is: how would I make my `.mod-prb > div` with `width: 100%` fits into `.mod-prb`.

Comment: So what you want is to avoid the inner box exceed the width of the outer box. Did I get it correctly now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why this happens**

This issue is happening because you are setting the width to 100%, but the inner box also has a padding of 10px (in left and right) and a border of 2px. That makes it have an actual width of 100% of its parent width + 20px (10px margin on both sides) + 4px (2px border on both sides).

**How to fix it**

You could fix it in different ways. The easiest one would be to use [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) with a value of `border-box`:

> The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin.

The code would look like this (note how the `height` changes too):

```css
.mod-prb {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #809097;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.mod-prb > div {
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  width:100%;
  border: inherit;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="mod mod-prb">
  <div class="perc"></div>
</div>
```